# JSON deserialization problems

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I want to convert this JSON that was returned from an API (OpenBank Project) into C#. But as a newbie, I have been having a ton of unnecessary problems.

```
{
  "banks": [
    {
      "id": "rbs",
      "short_name": "The Royal Bank of Scotland",
      "full_name": "The Royal Bank of Scotland",
      "logo": "http://www.red-bank-shoreditch.com/logo.gif",
      "website": "http://www.red-bank-shoreditch.com"
    },
    {
      "id": "test-bank",
      "short_name": "TB",
      "full_name": "Test Bank",
      "logo": null,
      "website": null
    },
    {
      "id": "testowy_bank_id",
      "short_name": "TB",
      "full_name": "Testowy bank",
      "logo": null,
      "website": null
    },
    {
      "id": "nordea",
      "short_name": "Nordea",
      "full_name": "Nordea Bank AB",
      "logo": "http://logonoid.com/images/nordea-logo.jpg",
      "website": "http://www.nordea.com/"
    },
    {
      "id": "nordeaab",
      "short_name": "Nordea",
      "full_name": "Nordea Bank AB",
      "logo": "http://logonoid.com/images/nordea-logo.jpg",
      "website": "http://www.nordea.com/"
    },
    {
      "id": "hsbc-test",
      "short_name": "HSBC Test",
      "full_name": "Hongkong and Shanghai Bank",
      "logo": null,
      "website": null
    },
    {
      "id": "erste-test",
      "short_name": "Erste Bank Test",
      "full_name": "Erste Bank Test",
      "logo": null,
      "website": null
    },
    {
      "id": "deutche-test",
      "short_name": "Deutche Bank Test",
      "full_name": "Deutche Bank Test",
      "logo": null,
      "website": null
    },
    {
      "id": "obp-bankx-m",
      "short_name": "Bank X",
      "full_name": "The Bank of X",
      "logo": "https://static.openbankproject.com/images/bankx/bankx_logo.png",
      "website": "https://www.example.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have verified the JSON string and it seems correct.

Now this is what I used to try to deserialize the content received:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
    bankslist info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<bankslist>(content);
}
```

These are the classes I´m using (I used json2csharp for this):

```
public class bankslist
{
    public List<banks> banklist { get; set; }
}

public class bankstuff
{
    public banks banks;
}

public class banks
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "short_name")]
    public string short_name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "full_name")]
    public string full_name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "logo")]
    public string logo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "website")]
    public string website { get; set; }
}
```

It seems that I am not saving any of the information that I want in the bank class.  I tried this but no info is showing:

```
foreach (var item in info.banklist)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("id=={0} .. full_name=={1} .. website=={2}", 
                    item.id, item.full_name, item.website);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  If one of the answers below worked for you, please mark it as accepted by clicking on the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  When you get a little more reputation you can also upvote answers that you find helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Brian, still learning the tricks of the trade over here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you used json2csharp, but when I put your JSON into json2csharp I get the following:

```
public class Bank
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string short_name { get; set; }
    public string full_name { get; set; }
    public string logo { get; set; }
    public string website { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Bank> banks { get; set; }
}
```

You then deserialize into the `RootObject`.

```
string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
var info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);
```

You can see it working here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yTcnQh

Comment: Helped a ton thanks for the quick response and simple resolution, that link that you put here is gonna help me a lot in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename the list of banks on your bankslist class from banklist to banks to match the json node:

```
public class bankslist
{
    public List<banks> banks { get; set; }
}
```